# How to Convert JSON Data Into a Python Object and display it in table

Tags: python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

i want to convert my data to json type in table please you can help me how to do it in service and this is my code :

**service.py** :

```
def get_droplets():
    headers = {'*****'}

    url = 'http://****/api/v4/projects/'
    url_r = 'http://*****/projects.json/'
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = requests.get(url_r, headers={'Authorization': 'Basic ******=='})
    droplets = r.json()
    droplet_list = []

    for i in range(len(droplets)):
        droplet_list.append(droplets[i])
    return droplet_list
```

**views.py**

```
class GetDroplets(TemplateView):
    template_name = "blog/home.html"

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = {
            "droplets": get_droplets(),
        }
        return context
```

Comment: can you also include the content of `r.json()` in your post.

Answer (score 0):

the response returned is something like `{...}` and you're expecting it to be `[...]`.
what you are doing is accessing keys using indices `droplets[i]` that do not exist in the dictionary.

Comment: droplet_list.append(droplets[i]) this ligne for save my data in the table !!

Comment: I already put that droplet = r.json () to transform my data api in json format

Comment: I'm asking you to include the output of the `r.json()` in your post.

Comment: sorry I do not understand what you mean ,  I got two errors in the execution   services.py", line 35, in get_droplets
    droplet_list.append(droplets[i])
KeyError: 0    line 136, in get_context_data
    'droplets' : get_droplets(),